# Unexpected extremely long query time (~5 minutes using nested WHEN-INs)

Tags: mysql, performance, join, normalization

For the first time, I am running up against a horrifically long execution time of a MySQL query (~5 minutes).

The data in the database is highly (and not arbitrarily) normalized. It very efficient at organizing and shuffling data to be displayed in a lot of very helpful ways for different purposes, except this one particular query is throwing a wrench into it.

I can't understand the reason for it. However, some background information that may shed some light onto otherwise arbitrarily convoluted queries.

---

The company has divided the world up into many many teams (**macroregions**). Everybody belongs to one or two teams, based on their expertise.

- For example, there are many diverse teams. A few examples are `Spanish`, `Sahara`, `Iberia`, `Portuguese`, `Jungle` teams. Each of the teams has considerable overlap with other teams, but is in some senses independent.
- The `Arabic` team works quite closely with the `Sahara` team, by virtue of the fact that the database tells them they have to work together on certain assignments, because of overlapping geographic locations. The `Spanish` and the `Portuguese` team also work closely together, they both work with the `Americas` and `Europe` teams and the `Portuguese` team also works with the `Africa` team, as does the `Arabic` team.
- Each team has a given set of regions, which are also not unique to that particular team. For example, the `Mediterranean` region belongs to around 12 teams, and when an event occurs there, they all work on it together.
- Each country belongs to one or more regions. `Turkey` belongs to `Central Asia`, `Europe` and even `Mediterranean`, and a few others.

Given all that, it is necessary to show each individual what other people on their teams are doing, as well as people who are not on their team, but have overlapping regions.

**Query 1** accomplishes this perfectly, and very quickly less than .09 seconds.

---

```
                SELECT report_name 
                FROM reports 
                WHERE region IN (
                    SELECT distinct region 
                    FROM macroregions
                    WHERE macroregion IN (
                        SELECT distinct macroregion
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE callsign = '$thisuser'
                    )
                )
```

It is also important people can see every occurrence of the `report_name`, when it Query 1 deems that the individual logged in should know about it. `Reports_names` are automatically generated and reused for each geographic location

- If I am on the `East Asia` team and someone in my area is working with the `Spanish` team, there would be two entries in the database:

  - `20120210JOMX01` `Japan` `Okinawa`
  - `20120210JOMX01` `Mexico` `Nuevo Leon`

**Query 2** takes **Query 1** and wraps one layer of `WHEN-IN`s around it. It allows the `East Asia` team members know that someone on their team is working in `Mexico`. But the performance delay is unacceptable and totally unusable; it takes nearly 5 minutes to complete a single query!

---

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM reports
        WHERE report_name IN (
            SELECT report_name 
            FROM reports 
            WHERE region IN (
                SELECT distinct region 
                FROM macroregions
                WHERE macroregion IN (
                    SELECT distinct macroregion
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE callsign = '$thisuser'
                )
            )    
        )
```

---

Despite the fact that the query works, it takes too long to be effective. Again, it is startling how long this particular query takes. Whereas nothing else in the interface has given me any sort of performance issue (i.e. they all take less than one second).

What steps can I take to fix this?

Comment: The optimizer is probably smart but you don't need `DISTINCT` in your queries: `IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ...`. Unless you have `NULL` in your columns.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the two `report_name` columns? Can you add in the question the query plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your original query

```
   SELECT *  
    FROM reports 
    WHERE report_name IN ( 
        SELECT report_name  
        FROM reports  
        WHERE region IN ( 
            SELECT distinct region  
            FROM macroregions 
            WHERE macroregion IN ( 
                SELECT distinct macroregion 
                FROM users  
                WHERE callsign = '$thisuser' 
            ) 
        )     
    )
```

You can gather keys only (in stages), then join the keys with the `reports` table. Here is my new proposed query

```
SELECT reports.* FROM
(
    SELECT rpts.report_name FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT regions.region FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT macroregion
        FROM users WHERE callsign = '$thisuser') users
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT macroregion,region FROM regions) regions
        USING (macroregion)
    ) regionkeys
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT region,report_name FROM reports) rpts
    USING (region)
) reportnamekeys
INNER JOIN reports
USING (report_name);
```

If you are not comfortable with the USING clause here is my new propsed query without using the USING clause:

```
SELECT reports.* FROM
(
    SELECT rpts.report_name FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT regions.region FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT macroregion
        FROM users WHERE callsign = '$thisuser') users
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT macroregion,region FROM regions) regions
        ON users.macroregion = regions.macroregion
    ) regionkeys
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT region,report_name FROM reports) rpts
    ON regionkeys.region = rpts.region
) reportnamekeys
INNER JOIN reports
ON reportkeys.report_name = reports.report_name;
```

You will need some indexes to support the subqueries

```
ALTER TABLE users   ADD INDEX callsign_macroregion_ndx (callsign,macroregion);
ALTER TABLE regions ADD INDEX macroregion_region_ndx (macroregion,region);
ALTER TABLE reports ADD INDEX region_report_name_ndx (region,report_name);
ALTER TABLE reports ADD INDEX report_name_ndx (report_name);
```

The first 3 indexes are called covering indexes. They are called such because the subqueries calls for only those exact columns. Therefore, no need to read from the table. The data is only fetched from the index.

- http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html
- http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/

You should also study how to refactor queries to gather keys, perform WHERE clauses early, and perform JOINs last. Here is great YouTube Video on how to do this: http://youtu.be/ZVisY-fEoMw (Based on this book : [**Refactoring SQL Applications**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006TR0ZEO))

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Postgres optimizer is different than MySQL's. Your query may be even slower than the original without the indexes (+1 for suggesting them).

Comment: WHOA! The first suggestion you had using `USING` was nearly instant. Sir, if I could give you a million upvotes. I would. Now, I have to go study what `USING` even does.

Comment: `USING` is just a fancy alternative way of doing a `NATURAL JOIN` so long as the two tables being joined have the same fieldnames being use in each table with the same datatypes.

Comment: If I may ask, how fast was the query and was the result it gave the correct result ???

Comment: 0.0010 seconds for my test run, my employee account has 761 reports that should appear. I am totally blown away, and I am going to pull out my text books it seems.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you have added to your answer. Thank you again, time to brush up it seems.

Answer (score 3):

First step: get rid of subqueries.  Convert them to proper joins, or co-related subqueries.