# 'SELECT my_table.id' slower than 'SELECT my_table.*'

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, query-performance

Running MySQL with InnoDB:

I have a `SELECT wide_table.*` query that I want to refine to `SELECT wide_table.id` since that's all the calling code needs. Testing it out I've found that the execution time with `*` is faster than with `id` (though the time to transfer the result over the network is faster with the "refined" version).

Why would this be the case?

The query (with names changed to protect the innocent) is:

```
SELECT
    `things`.*
FROM
    `things`
WHERE
    `things`.`active` = 1
        AND (owner_id IS NOT NULL
        AND owner_id > 0)
        AND ((`things`.`status` IN (0 , 1)
        OR `things`.`status` IS NULL))
        AND (date < '2015-07-11 00:00:00');
```

There's a compound index on `active` and `date`, which is being used in both versions.

For reference, the ouput of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with irrelevant columns omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE `things` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_things_on_active_and_date` (`active`,`date`),
  KEY `index_things_on_date` (`date`),
  KEY `index_things_on_owner_id` (`owner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1862 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

## ***Limits***

After playing around with it for a while, I've found that the comparison is affected by the limit imposed on the query. With large limits, >200, the `*` version reports a faster execution time. As the limit is decreased <200, the `id` version gains the upper-hand. Still not sure what to make of this...

## ***EXPLAIN***

Running `EXPLAIN` on both versions of the query yields identical output, with select_type: `SIMPLE` and key: `index_things_on_active_and_date`.

Comment: Can you post your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in your question?

Comment: Try running q1 several times, then q2 several times (to minimize effects of caching). Do the execution times still differ significantly?

Comment: @Lennart I tried that and yeah, they're still significantly different.

Comment: @ivan Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) on both queries and check/post the plans used, it should tell you what is done differently.

Comment: @jkavalik Running EXPLAIN on both versions gives me the same report. I'll include it above in the description of my question. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Try please to optimize the table then run again. i.e. `OPTIMIZE TABLE things`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXPLAIN plan for `SELECT *` and `SELECT id`, which you said were identical, would be separated by the number of rows accessed. How are the rows being accessed ? Through the `index_things_on_active_and_date` index.  The `SIMPLE` in the EXPLAIN means it is a scan. In both cases, it is an index scan based on `active=1` and `date < '2015-07-11 00:00:00'`

How does the index scan occur ?

- Since the chosen index has `active` and `date`, the range scan would occur from two columns.
- Look at the `WHERE` clause. You are retrieving `owner_id` and `status` and checking the values. This requires you accessing the whole row.

  - `SELECT *` means you make the whole row part of the result set
  - `SELECT id` means you make the id part of the result set

Where is this leading up to ?

- In both cases, you are reading an entire row to check two additional columns not in the index.
- The result set of each query is either an entire row or single column (id).
- It must take some additional time to create a smaller result set. Why ? There comes a point when a longer result of `id` values would take longer the build that going with the whole row you read anyway. You yourself empirically tested that and discovered the following:

  - `< 200 rows` -> `SELECT id` is faster
  - `> 200 rows` -> `SELECT *` is faster
  - `= 200 rows` -> `SELECT id` and `SELECT *` are about the same

There is something else you need to realize about InnoDB

- [InnoDB stores data for a row is stored along with the index pages making up the PRIMARY KEY. This is known as the clustered index (gen_clust_index)](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554)
- Non-unique indexes will store the primary key fields of row along with the index entries.

This tells you that the index `index_things_on_active_and_date` actually has three columns: 1) `active`, 2) `date`, 3) `id`.

You are probably saying: Why is `SELECT *` running better that `SELECT id`? (which is the original question) It goes back to what I said: ***the WHERE clause is causing the Query Optimizer to check non-indexed columns `status` and `owner_id`***. You are creating additional work check an index entry and something from the row that is indexed.

If you create this index

```
ALTER TABLE things
    ADD INDEX index_everything_and_kitchen_sink
    (active,date,owner_id,status)
;
```

and run the two queries, then you will see the advantage go to `SELECT id` no matter how many rows you are accessing. Why ? Because **all the columns in the WHERE clause are checked from the index only**. This type of index is called a covering index.

Here are some good links about covering indexes

- http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/
- http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/

I mentioned these links in some of my answers:

- `Feb 10, 2012` [Unexpected extremely long query time (~5 minutes using nested WHEN-INs)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12606/unexpected-extremely-long-query-time-5-minutes-using-nested-when-ins/12614#12614)
- `Oct 17, 2012` : [Combining columns in index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27097/combining-columns-in-index/27111#27111)
- `Jan 11, 2013` : [MySQL: To use MYISAM or INNODB engine? (plot twist enclosed)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31735/mysql-to-use-myisam-or-innodb-engine-plot-twist-enclosed/31736#31736)